# what does data types in html5 means

Tags: html

I didn't get what does it really mean, when someone refers to data types in **html5**.
I googled it, and found http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html
It says,

> data types (*microsyntaxes*) that are referenced by attribute
>   descriptions

But, now I'm even confused what it means with `micorsyntaxes`.

Comment: **Who** is this "we" that say "data types in HTML5"?

Comment: Do you mean `data-` attributes and the associated Javascript API? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: I believe you're referring to data attributes http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: @OllyHodgson I don't think that it is talking about the particular attribute instead it's a concept. I'm not sure ?!?!

Comment: If you look at documentation about HTML5 attributes (e.g. [this for global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html)), you should notice that each attribute says what type of data it accepts (e.g. `onabort = functionbody` means it accepts data of type `functionbody`). These types are formally enumerated in the document you linked to.

Comment: @DCoder Thanks for brief explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_%28programming_languages%29):

> [...] the syntax of a computer language is the set of rules that defines the combinations of symbols that are considered to be a correctly structured document or fragment in that language. This applies both to programming languages, where the document represents source code, and markup languages, where the document represents data.

So in order for an HTML document to be read and understood by a browser, it should adhere to the syntax of HTML: That is, it should follow the rules that define the language. A microsyntax is essentially a very small syntax, applying to a very specific thing.

A data type is simply a type of data. The HTML specifications refer to various data types (e.g. `String`, `Token`, `Integer`, `Date`, `Set of comma-separated strings`, etc) and [the document you linked](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html) describes exactly what those things are. It does this by defining a set of rules, or a microsyntax.

E.g. the microsyntax which defines a `Set of comma-separated strings` is:

> Zero or more strings that are themselves each zero or more characters, each optionally with leading and/or trailing space characters, and each separated from the next by a single "," (comma) character. Each string itself must not begin or end with any space characters, and each string itself must not contain any "," (comma) characters.